# Почему компилятор не может автоматически вывести тип шаблона класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Есть вот такой код

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(U v) : field1{}, field2(v) {}

private:
    T field1;
    U field2;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> b("");
}
```

Собирается clang14, 17 стандарт. Получаю ошибку компиляции error:

> too few template arguments for class template 'A'

Почему компилятор автоматически не выводит тип?

Comment: Потому что присутствует список параметров шаблона при инстанцировании. Избавитесь от `<int>` - тогда `U` будет успешно выводиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для шаблонов классов, в отличие от функций, выводятся или все шаблонные аргументы, или никакие. Если указать хотя бы один аргумент, то остальные не будут выводиться.

Это обходят так:

```
template <typename T> struct tag {};

template <typename T, typename U>
class A
{
  public:
    explicit A(tag<T>, U v) : field1{}, field2(v) {}

  private:
    T field1;
    U field2;
};

int main()
{
    A b(tag<int>{}, "");
}
```

Comment: Где это в стандарте? а то я полчаса рылся вчера, потом плюнул, а без стандарта как-то...

Comment: @Harry Во: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#3 Пишут, что когда шаблонные аргументы не указаны (имя шаблона без аргументов они называют *template-name*), то все эта штука называется *placeholder-type-specifier* (заглушка под вывод типа).

Comment: То ли язык у них, как у юристов :), то ли я туповат с утра, но не понял, на основании чего тут можно сделать вывод, что либо должны быть указаны все шаблонные аргументы, либо ни одного... :(

Comment: @Harry Угу, это у них язык дурацкий. Если аргументы указаны, то это больше не считается placeholder-type-specifier (потому что тот должен заканчиваться template-name, а он не может содержать треугольных скобок), а вывод аргументов делается только для placeholder-type-specifier, а для других форм указания типа не делается (не могу найти, где это бы прямо в лоб говорилось, но везде пишут про "placeholder", как в http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct).